# Create Bitmap in C# from char[] buffer

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, named-pipes

I've got to interface my C++ project with a C# project and send an image to it across a named pipe. OpenCV stores matrix data in a contiguous chunk, starting at `uchar* Mat::data`. However, to send data across a named pipe, it must be a `char*`, so I just do a cast, not sure what else I'm supposed to do. It shouldn't matter, it's just data, not characters.

```
size_t s = frame2.elemSize() * frame2.rows * frame2.cols;
sendChars(hPipe, (char*)frame2.data, s);
```

On the C# side I read in the block of data to a `char[]` buffer. I then create a new `Bitmap` with the appropriate width, height, etc. and set the IntPtr to the beginning of the `char[] buffer`.

```
  //in the C# forms private scope:
  char[] buffer = new char[921600];
```

and then in a `StartServer()` function:

```
    pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("SamplePipe", PipeDirection.InOut);
    //blah blah blah
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer))
    {
        sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (char* ptr = buffer)
            {
                using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(640, 480, 640*3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new IntPtr(ptr)))
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                    image.Save("test.png");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The result of this is a big red X on the C# form and the saved image looks garbled... but not just random noise. So the data's coming through and getting messed up either on the C++ end before transmission or the C# end on interpretation. I have tried to work around this by using the Bitmap constructor that reads a stream and sending an encoded image instead of the raw pixels, but that fails harder than the above method (just gives an error, no output).

[image: what it looks like]

How do I transfer uchar* array with pixel data from C++ to C# and then reconstruct it inside a Bitmap so that I can display it on the form?

Comment: You need to get your data types figured out. `unsigned char` in C++ is `byte` in C#; `char` in C# is `wchar_t` in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of a `StreamReader` here seems like the wrong choice if what you're sending is actually binary data. The `StreamReader` is used for reading text, and will decode the data to characters with some encoding which in your case would be auto-detected (and definitely wrong).

You want to use the `BinaryReader` for reading binary data, or read directly from the `NamedPipeServerStream` using the `Read()` method to get a `byte[]` array. A `char` in C# is used for storing characters, and is unicode, not a single byte.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise StreamReader was meant for text -__-

Comment: You're welcome. It's name could definitely have been better, but it actually inherits from the `TextReader` class, even though that is probably not the first thing one looks for. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use stream the easiest way would be to use the SetPixel method of Bitmap to construct the image.

Comment: That would be horribly slow. Each SetPixel call would have to lock and unlock the entire bitmap surface one pixel at a time.